Question in the proof existence of valuative criterion
The lemma 26.20.5 states:

Let $f:X→S$ be a morphism of schemes. The following are equivalent:

Specializations lift along any base change of $f$
The morphism $f$ satisfies the existence part of the valuative criterion.


I don't understand the following from the proof:

Assume (1) holds. In order to find the dotted arrow we may replace $X→S$ by $X_{\text{Spec}(A)}→\text{Spec}(A)$ since after all, the assumption is stable under base change. Thus we may assume $S=\text{Spec}(A)$.

My questions (edited):

What is the meaning of specializations lift along any base change of $f$?
The definition here is only for specializations lift along $f$.
Does it mean that if $f:X\rightarrow S$ is morphism and specializations lift along $f$ then specializations also lift along $X_{\text{Spec}(A)}→\text{Spec}(A)$?
Therefore, we can replace $X→S$ by $X_{\text{Spec}(A)}→\text{Spec}(A).$

After replacing $X→S$ by $X_{\text{Spec}(A)}→\text{Spec}(A)$, I guess we have the following diagram:


$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\text{Spec}(K) @>{}>> X_{\text{Spec}(A)} @>{}>> X\\
@VVV @VVV @VVV\\
\text{Spec}(A) @>{}>> \text{Spec}(A) @>{}>> S          
\end{CD}$$
But I'm still unable to figure out why we can assume $S=\text{Spec}(A)$. Do we show the existence of the lift $\text{Spec}(A)\rightarrow X_{\text{Spec}(A)}$ and thus the existence of $\text{Spec}(A)\rightarrow X_{\text{Spec}(A)}\rightarrow X$?
As Daniel pointed out in the comment, this is a standard reduction in algebraic geometry. However, at the moment, I'm unable to figure out this reduction. So, perhaps a link to any source may help.

"Specializations lift along any base change of $f$ " means that if $g: S' \to S$ is a morphism and $f': X' \to S'$ is the base change of $f$ along $g$, then specializations lift along $f'$.
For example, if we take $S' = S$ we see that specializations lift along $f$. Also, it is immediate from the definition that this condition is stable under base change.
As for the reduction, we need to show that if $(1) \implies (2)$ is known for $S$ affine, then it is known for any $S$. Let $(A, \mathfrak{m}_A)$ be a valuation ring with fraction field $K$ so that there is a diagram as below. $\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\operatorname{Spec} K @>>> X\\
@VVV @VVV\\
\operatorname{Spec} A @>>> S
\end{CD}
We claim that this square factors as
\begin{CD}
\operatorname{Spec} K @>>> X_{\operatorname{Spec} R} @>>> X\\
@VVV @VVV @VVV\\
\operatorname{Spec} A @>>> \operatorname{Spec} R @>>>S
\end{CD}
where this right square is the pullback square along an affine open subset $\operatorname{Spec} R \subset S$. Then, by the affine case, the map $X_{\operatorname{Spec} R} \to \operatorname{Spec} R$ satisfies (1) so there is a diagonal map $\operatorname{Spec} A \to X_{\operatorname{Spec R}}$ which we can compose with $X_{\operatorname{Spec} R} \to X$ to get the required existence in (2).
Factoring the square like this is not too bad - we just need to think explicitly about the data of these maps. A map $\operatorname{Spec} K \to X$ is the same as picking a point $x \in X$ and an extension $k(x) \subset K$. A map $\operatorname{Spec} A \to X$ fitting into the diagram is a choice of specialization $s \in \overline{\{f(x)\}}$ so that $A$ dominates the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{\overline{\{f(x)\}}, s}$, where we give $\overline{\{f(x)\}}$ the reduced scheme structure. (cf. Hartshorne Lemma II.4.4)
With this perspective, it's not hard to see that we have the above decomposition if we take $\operatorname{Spec} R$ an affine open subset of $s$ in $S$. I'll leave this to you for now.

In the second line, I guess you mean then specializations lift along $f'$. Anyway, thank you for the answer:)

That's right, thanks. No problem! @Anon12
